# Movie about about alien invasion and resistance by kamikazes wearing bombs in a forest that's sucked by the aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, alien-invasion

I once watched this movie about alien invasion long time ago (maybe 10 years ago). I only have a little clue about it. The only thing I remember is this alien spaceship suck forest and maybe other Earth resources as well and there are several people trying to destroy it using suicide bombing (they get sucked to the spaceship with bombs armed while the spaceship sucked a forest).

I'm sure it's not animated. I saw it on TV and I think it's box office / Hollywood movie but I don't really remember.

Comment: I remember the movie about as you described and want to see it again. It was not animated. It seems like they put bombs in the trees and when they were sucked up in the alien craft, they exploded them from the inside, kinda like a hand grenade thrown in a tank. I haven't been able to find it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*When Aliens Attack*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1933522/) - National Geographic Channel  A sort of speculative documentary from 2011.

Aliens invade.  Humans are severely out classed/gunned.  The aliens are after chlorophyll (hence sucking up the forests).  We send sick people into the forests to get sucked up with the trees trying to get the invaders sick, it doesn’t work (drones or wrong physiology I can’t remember) so we send people up in balloons with bombs to destroy the machines from the inside.  If I remember the only way Humans win is if we make it resource costly for them to stay.
It has a lot of talking heads explaining that other than chlorophyll, Earth has nothing that aliens couldn’t get easy.  Minerals and water are plentiful in space (asteroids, comets, gas clouds).  And if they have the technology to survive getting here, we wouldn’t be much of an obstacle.

Comment: OP says that they watched it some 10 years ago. It can't have been a speculative documentary from 2011.

Comment: the synopsis quite convince me. too bad i can't find any trailer/video to confirm it. About the year when i watched, maybe it's my mistake to not exactly remember. thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like the [first episode of the fourth and final season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lexx_episodes) of [*Lexx*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexx), titled "Little Blue Planet," wherein the eponymous ship feeds on a big chunk on the Amazon rainforest (along with anything else it could get its feeders on).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure it is this one.